# Finding records that are lacking a previous designation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bit of code I can't figure out, and I'm sure the answer is here, but the search terms I've used haven't been successful.

I am trying to select records from my database where a competitor has moved to a higher level of competition, before getting their accreditation from the lower level.

The higher level in this scenario is under the Class_Subset column, RO being the higher level. 
And the accreditation from the lower level is under the Title column. NAC being the accreditation.

I have a bit of code written but it obviously doesn't work.

All I need is to select the records where a person has records with RO listed as the Class_Subset, but have do not have a NAC in the title column for that competitors records.

Here is the SQL Fiddle.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b65e0b

RegNum is what groups the competitors records together.

The picture below illustrates the issue and what is needed.  Sorry for the lack of text based data.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRSGj.jpg

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question as text*.

Answer (score 0):

Returns two rows. 
 Using Not Exists meaning the regNum does not have a Class NAC but only with a subset of RO

```
select * from points p
where class_subset = 'RO'
and not exists (
  select 1 from points p1
  where p1.regNum = p.regNum
  and p1.Class = 'NAC'

  )
```

Comment: Gave it a try and I believe the reason it isn't working is because the subset is different for the lower level.   If that makes sense.    So the NAC would never be on the same record as the RO.   It would be on the same line as RN which is the lower level.   I'll try to get some data posted like someone mentioned

Comment: please do because i based the solution from your statement "All I need is to select the records where a person has records with RO listed as the Class_Subset, but have do not have a NAC in the title column for that competitors records."

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.   I'm probably as confused as anyone reading this, ha

Comment: Just added a photo to the original question illustrating what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
SELECT * FROM Points t1 left join Points t2 On t1.RegNum = t2.RegNum where t1.Class_Subset = 'RN' AND t2.Class_Subset = 'RN'  AND t2.Class != 'NAC';
```